# Compare unsigned T with 0: what can possibly go wrong?

Tags: c, generic-programming, comparison-operators

Maybe a silly question, but today I've faced this type-generic code:

```
float f_u( unsigned T v )
{
    if ( v == 0u )
    {
        return 0.0f;
    }
    ...
    return result;
}
```

Is `unsigned-suffix` `u` really needed in this case?

In other words: what can possibly go wrong without using `u`?

UPD.

1. The question is about `C`, not `C++`. Updated code sample.
2. Answer to https://xyproblem.info: the `actual problem` is: there are another function `f_s()` for `signed T v`, which uses `if ( v == u )`. Now I'm thinking of merging `f_u()` with `f_s()` into common `f_x()`. The `actual problem`: in `f_x()` do I need to keep this `u` or it can be safely omitted?

Comment: More context is needed. Apparently you have some template which needs fixing. Now question suffers from [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: `what can possibly go wrong without using u?` You can get a compiler warning about signed/unsigned comparison and I think similar MISRA issue.

Comment: @KamilCuk Does it really ever warn about comparing unsigned integers with signed zero? I don't think I ever saw that

Comment: There's `-Wsign-compare` in gcc, but it does not work with constants. Indeed.

Comment: `if(!v)` works the same for both signed and unsigned, without having to provide a literal constant.

Comment: Maybe a more precise question: is there any unsigned integer type `T` for which, given `T x;` the expression `x == 0` ever has different observable behavior from `x == 0u`?  I don't believe so, but it's possible I miss something.